# Gödel's incompleteness theorems for soundness or semantic consistency

Tags: logic, turing-machines, incompleteness

I am learning about Gödel's incompleteness theorems, and I want to prove them using the undecidability of the halting problem. So far, here is the result I have been able to prove:

> **Theorem 1** (First Incompleteness Theorem, soundness version). *Let $S$ be a formal system such that:*
>
> *a) $S$ is recursively axiomatizable (that is, its axioms are recursively enumerable).*
>
> *b) $S$ is sound (that is, every theorem --or provable formula-- is true).*
>
> *c) $S$ can express certain statements about Turing machines, specifically, it can encode, given a Turing machine $M$, that "$M$ halts on empty input".*
>
> *Then, $S$ is semantically incomplete, that is, there are true formulas in $S$ that are not provable.*

**Note:** I give a proof of this theorem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4700476/g%c3%b6dels-first-incompleteness-theorem-from-halting-problem-using-soundness-is-it).

This version is different than Gödel's:

> **Theorem 2** (Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem). *Let $S$ be a formal system such that:*
>
> *a) $S$ is recursively axiomatizable (in the same sense as theorem 1).*
>
> *b) $S$ is syntactically consistent (it is not possible that both $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ are provable).*
>
> *c) $S$ contains a certain amount of elementary arithmetic.*
>
> *Then, $S$ is syntactically incomplete, that is, there are formulas $\phi$ in $S$ such that $\phi$ nor $\neg\phi$ are provable.*

For one, Gödel's version is entirely syntactical, while the one from the halting problem is semantic. My question is, is there any semantic result like the following?

> **Theorem 3** (Second Incompleteness Theorem, soundness version). *Let $S$ be a formal system such that:*
>
> *a) $S$ is recursively axiomatizable.*
>
> *b) $S$ can express certain statements about Turing machines, specifically, it can encode, given a Turing machine $M$, that "$M$ halts on empty input".*
>
> *Then, $S$ cannot prove its own soundness (that is, every provable formula is true).*

It would be like a *dual* version of Theorem 1, in the sense that Theorem 4 is a *dual* version of Theorem 2.

> **Theorem 4** (Gödel's Second Incompleteness Theorem). *Let $S$ be a formal system such that:*
>
> *a) $S$ is recursively axiomatizable.*
>
> *b) $S$ contains a certain amount of elementary arithmetic.*
>
> *Then, $S$ cannot prove its own syntactic consistency (it is not possible that both $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ are provable).*

**Edit:** I asked this question about soundness, but given that soundness implies consistency (in a way that I do not know), I would also like to ask if it is possible to prove that:

> **Theorem 5** (Second Incompleteness Theorem, semantic consistency version). *Let $S$ be a formal system such that:*
>
> *a) $S$ is recursively axiomatizable.*
>
> *b) $S$ can express certain statements about Turing machines, specifically, it can encode, given a Turing machine $M$, that "$M$ halts on empty input".*
>
> *Then, $S$ cannot prove its own semantic consistency (that is, given a formula $\phi$, it is not possible that both $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ are true).*

Comment: Note that soundness implies consistency, provably in a very weak theory. So the soundness-versions of the theorems are direct consequences of the consistency-versions.

Comment: I do not get why soundness implies consistency. I have tried to prove it but can't come up with a formal proof about that @NoahSchweber - Also, which kind of consistency is implied by soundness? Semantic or syntactic? Both?

Comment: Sound means that it proves only true formulas while a contradiction is false.