# Gödel's first incompleteness theorem from halting problem using soundness. Is it possible to use semantic consistency?

Tags: logic, turing-machines, incompleteness

Here is my proof of a variation of Gödel's first incompleteness theorem (Theorem 1). It uses **soundness** as one of the hypothesis. I would like to know if it would be possible to prove Theorem 2.

> **Theorem 1** (First Incompleteness Theorem, soundness version). *Let $S$ be a formal system such that:*
>
> *a) $S$ is recursively axiomatizable (that is, its axioms are recursively enumerable).*
>
> *b) $S$ is sound (that is, every theorem --or provable formula-- is true).*
>
> *c) $S$ can express certain statements about Turing machines, specifically, it can encode, given a Turing machine $M$, that "$M$ halts on empty input".*
>
> *Then, $S$ is semantically incomplete, that is, there are true formulas in $S$ that are not provable.*

Here is how I would prove it. Consider the following program, `godel.py`:

```
import is_theorem_in_S
import halt_to_S

def godel(input):
    godel_program = read('godel.py')
    halts_in_S = halt_to_S(godel_program)
    not_halts_in_S = 'NOT ' + halts_in_S

    if is_proof_in_S(not_halts_in_S) == 'yes':
        return 'halts'
    else:
        # loop
        while True:
            pass
```

We import two functions:

- `is_theorem_in_S` checks if the given formula is a theorem in $S$ (that is, if it is provable). This function will stop if the formula is provable, and loop if it is not. This is due to the fact that $S$ is recursively axiomatizable, a).
- `halt_to_S` turns, or a given input program $P$, the statement "$P$ halts with empty input" into a formula in $S$. This is possible because of c).

`halts_in_S` stores the formula equivalent to "`godel.py` halts on empty input", and:

> `not_halts_in_S` stores the formula equivalent to "`godel.py` does NOT halt on empty input"  (1)

If `not_halts_in_S` is a theorem, the function `is_proof_in_S(not_halts_in_S)` will return `'yes'` and the problem will halt. If not, the program will enter an infinite loop.

The question is, what happens to `godel.py` when `input` is empty (`''`)?

If we assume `godel.py` stops on empty input, the only way to do so is because it returned `'halts'`, and this can only happen if `is_proof_in_S(not_halts_in_S) == 'yes'`, hence it can only happen if `not_halts_in_S` is a theorem. Because of the soundness of $S$ (b), `not_halts_in_S` would be true.

But if `not_halts_in_S` is true, then, using (1), that would mean `godel.py` does not stop on empty input, which gives a contradiction.

We now know that:

> `godel.py` does not halt on empty input (2)

Let's check that `not_halts_in_S` is true but is not a theorem. It is true because of (2). However, `not_halts_in_S` is not a theorem. For that, we use (2) again. The fact that `godel.py` does not halt means that it is not possible that `is_proof_in_S(not_halts_in_S) == 'yes'`, in other words, `not_halts_in_S` is not a theorem.

We have found a statement in $S$ that is true but is not a theorem. This means that $S$ is semantically incomplete.

---

Would it be possible to tweak this proof so that we can prove Theorem 2?

> **Theorem 2** (First Incompleteness Theorem, semantic consistency version). *Let $S$ be a formal system such that:*
>
> *a) $S$ is recursively axiomatizable (that is, its axioms are recursively enumerable).*
>
> *b) $S$ is semantically consistent (that is, it is not possible that, given a formula $\phi$, both $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ are true).*
>
> *c) $S$ can express certain statements about Turing machines, specifically, it can encode, given a Turing machine $M$, that "$M$ halts on empty input".*
>
> *Then, $S$ is semantically incomplete, that is, there are true formulas in $S$ that are not provable.*

Comment: I have not checked all of the details of your question (sorry, but I am not good at understanding programming codes) but you should check Rosser's trick, which eliminates $\Sigma_1$-soundness assumption in Gödel's original proof.